# More practical way to add my code to original method

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

So i'm overriding `_prepare_invoice_line_from_po_line` method. I'm satisfied with the result I'm getting but I want to make the code more elegant. Basically, it's copy past from original method but I only added a small part of it ( you can check it below). How can I add my code to this method without copy/past all original method?

```
 class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    price_by_pricelist = fields.Float("Price by Pricelist")
    line_color = fields.Boolean()

    @api.multi
    def _prepare_invoice_line_from_po_line(self, line):
        super(AccountInvoice,self)._prepare_invoice_line_from_po_line(line)
        if line.product_id.purchase_method == 'purchase':
            qty = line.product_qty - line.qty_invoiced
        else:
            qty = line.qty_received - line.qty_invoiced
        if float_compare(qty, 0.0, precision_rounding=line.product_uom.rounding) <= 0:
            qty = 0.0
        taxes = line.taxes_id
        invoice_line_tax_ids = self.purchase_id.fiscal_position_id.map_tax(taxes)
        invoice_line = self.env['account.invoice.line']
        data = {
            'purchase_line_id': line.id,
            'name': line.name,
            'origin': self.purchase_id.origin,
            'uom_id': line.product_uom.id,
            'product_id': line.product_id.id,
            'account_id': invoice_line.with_context({'journal_id': self.journal_id.id, 'type': 'in_invoice'})._default_account(),
            'price_unit': line.order_id.currency_id.compute(line.price_unit, self.currency_id, round=False),
            'quantity': qty,
            'discount': 0.0,
            'account_analytic_id': line.account_analytic_id.id,
            'invoice_line_tax_ids': invoice_line_tax_ids.ids,
            'price_by_pricelist': line.product_id.seller_ids[0].price,
        }

        if data['price_by_pricelist'] != line.price_unit:
            self.line_color = True

        account = invoice_line.get_invoice_line_account('in_invoice', line.product_id, self.purchase_id.fiscal_position_id, self.env.user.company_id)
        if account:
            data['account_id'] = account.id

        return data
```

My part

```
 'price_by_pricelist': line.product_id.seller_ids[0].price,
       if data['price_by_pricelist'] != line.price_unit:
            self.line_color = True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this should do the trick.

```
data = super(AccountInvoice,self)._prepare_invoice_line_from_po_line(line)
data.update({'price_by_pricelist': line.product_id.seller_ids[0].price}) # update the dictionary

if data['price_by_pricelist'] != line.price_unit:
     self.line_color = True

return data
```

### Steps:

1. Call super() to return the data from the original function
2. update the dictionary with the data you want
3. Do your data manipulation and what have you
4. return the data

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Good answer. Try to use `super()` calls whenever possible to override methods. But there are a lot of methods that are not that easy to "manipulate".

Comment: always a treat when it works out this neatly. oh yeah and python 3 you can just call `super()` :P